# How to make dropdown items "clickable" by enter button?

Tags: drop-down-menu, keyboard-shortcuts, accessibility, dropdown, semantic-ui

I'm developing an app with Angular and Semantic-UI.

I have a dropdown menu like the following: https://plnkr.co/edit/BTCxfk

```
<div class="ui right labeled top pointing floating icon button dropdown">
    <i class="icon folder open"></i>
    <span class="text">Menu</span>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="item" (click)="onClickItem()" *ngFor="#m of menu">
            <i class="icon sign in"></i>
            {{m}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to have that users can click on a single item using `tab` and `enter` buttons.

As you can see they can only move towards menu items, but they can't trigger the click event.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you looked at Heydon Pickerings [Inclusive Components Menus & Menu Buttons](https://inclusive-components.design/menus-menu-buttons/)?

Answer (score 0):

I would give this item a tab-index of 0 since most elements like this aren't tabbable by default.

```
<div class="ui right labeled top pointing floating icon button dropdown">
    <i class="icon folder open"></i>
    <span class="text" tabindex="0" role="menu">Menu</span>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="item" (click)="onClickItem()" *ngFor="#m of menu">
            <i class="icon sign in"></i>
            {{m}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I added tab index of 0 and role of menu.

Comment: I asked for "pressable" button, not "tabbable".